# SVN in Xcode 4.3 issues

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, svn

I have already created a repo in my xcode, what im trying to do is import my project. And commit. Im kinda new to this thing, so I dont know what Im doing wrong.

When I try to import my project, this error came out:

[image]

Hope someone can help me.

EDITED:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904939/xcode-4-2-svn-issues

please check this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the [import](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re12.html) by hand and answer the question "(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently?" with "p".

After that, you should be able to use the XCode frontend to svn without problems (beside that XCode comes with a rather old svn version, which can not work with newer repositories).

**EDIT**

By hand, I mean to do it within the terminal:

- Start the Teriminal.app
- Change to the directory where your project exist: `cd [yourDir]`
- Import the project to svn: `svn -m 'initial import' import [yourURL]`
- Answer the "(R)eject, accept..." question with "p"

**2nd EDIT**

If the `svn` command is not in your path (you will get `command not found`), you have to use the full path, e.g. `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/svn` instead of `svn` only.

Comment: I tried answering/pressing it with P but It doesnt do anything.

Comment: With "by hand" I mean within the terminal. XCode does not gives your answer back to the svn program.

Comment: i dont know how with the terminal.

Comment: /Users/USERNAME/Desktop/PROJECTNAME? something like this? then outputs `is a directory` but when import, says `command not found`

Comment: Xcode 4.x support for SVN still leaves a little to be desired, so get familiar with svn'ing from the command line in general. There's no way, for example, to do a full "rollback" within Xcode. You MUST use the command line for that and other operations.

Comment: nows have an error `Could not use external editor to fetch log message; consider setting the $SVN_EDITOR environment variable or using the --message (-m) or --file (-F) options
svn: None of the environment variables SVN_EDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR are set, and no 'editor-cmd' run-time configuration option was found`

Comment: I adapted the answer for your case. However, you should better set one of the named environment variables (e.g. to `vi` or `nano`)

Comment: was able to import but i think im having problem with my project directories when commiting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317408/xcode-commit-missing-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

open terminal app and  type following command

svn co 'type your svn url '

I saw the same error on the prompt as in xcode:

Error validating server certificate for 'https://mysvnserver.com:443':
 - The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the
   fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!
Certificate information:
 - Hostname: *.svn.mysvnserver.com
....
....
....
R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently? 
Now  hit  p here to accept (p)ermanently, and I was able to access the repository via the prompt. Next, I opened xcode and opened the repository -- everything worked flawlessly.