# Non existing files appear when committing (and pushing) in Xcode using git

Tags: ios, xcode, git, github

I've been struggling with this issue for a while and it really started to piss me off.

I'm working on this app for iOS that is using git for source control and I'm hosting the code in GitHub. 
Everything was going cool until I had a folder called "Titulación" which contained only images. 
When I tried to commit, I got the following error:

> error: pathspec 'UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulación/boton-documentos.png' did not match any file(s) known to git.

So I thought somehow, the word "Titulación" had something to do about it. I deleted it, and created a new folder without the written accent but with the same contents. It worked, but now every time I try to commit new changes, the old folder still appears under the file view section. It actually shows the old images too!
Here's a screenshot: [Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a3xbkz24s2lyxap/Screenshot%202014-06-16%2008.39.58.png)

That folder is not either in Xcode Project Navigator nor in Finder anymore. I thought it might have been hidden for some reason, but no, it does not exists anywhere!

So now when I make changes in my code or when I add new files, I have to uncheck everything first and then check the files that actually exists.
I've been doing this for some days, but it's getting really annoying to uncheck all files because of those non existing images.

I have tried this: [Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317408/xcode-commit-missing-file-or-directory) but it did not work out :(

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATED**

Thank you trojanfoe for you quick answer. 
This is the whole output:

```
On branch master
```

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)

```
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/boton-documentos.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/boton-documentos@2x.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/boton-titulacion-TI.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/boton-titulacion-TI@2x.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/boton-titulacion.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/boton-titulacion@2x.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/cerrar.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/cerrar@2x.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/certificado-estudios.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/certificado-estudios@2x.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/informacion.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/informacion@2x.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/informate.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/informate@2x.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/llamar.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/llamar@2x.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/opcion-titulacion.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/opcion-titulacion@2x.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/over-informacion.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/over-informacion@2x.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/over-llamar.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/over-llamar@2x.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/over-tramites.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/over-tramites@2x.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/revision-estudios.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/revision-estudios@2x.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/toma-protesta.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/toma-protesta@2x.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/over-documentos.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/over-documentos@2x.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/over-titulacion-TI.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/over-titulacion-TI@2x.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/over-titulacion.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/over-titulacion@2x.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/alto-redimiento.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/alto-redimiento@2x.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/guia-metodologica.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/guia-metodologica@2x.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/opciones-titulacion.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/opciones-titulacion@2x.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/over-alto-rendimiento.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/over-alto-rendimiento@2x.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/over-seminario.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/over-seminario@2x.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/over-tesis-profesional.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/over-tesis-profesional@2x.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/seminario.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/seminario@2x.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/tesis-profesional.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/tesis-profesional@2x.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/top-titulacion.png"
new file:   "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/top-titulacion@2x.png"
```

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm ..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)

```
modified:   UNEVE.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/Thurman.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/boton-documentos.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/boton-documentos@2x.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/boton-titulacion-TI.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/boton-titulacion-TI@2x.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/boton-titulacion.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/boton-titulacion@2x.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/cerrar.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/cerrar@2x.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/certificado-estudios.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/certificado-estudios@2x.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/informacion.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/informacion@2x.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/informate.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/informate@2x.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/llamar.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/llamar@2x.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/opcion-titulacion.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/opcion-titulacion@2x.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/over-informacion.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/over-informacion@2x.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/over-llamar.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/over-llamar@2x.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/over-tramites.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/over-tramites@2x.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/revision-estudios.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/revision-estudios@2x.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/toma-protesta.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/documentos/toma-protesta@2x.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/over-documentos.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/over-documentos@2x.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/over-titulacion-TI.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/over-titulacion-TI@2x.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/over-titulacion.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/over-titulacion@2x.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/alto-redimiento.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/alto-redimiento@2x.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/guia-metodologica.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/guia-metodologica@2x.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/opciones-titulacion.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/opciones-titulacion@2x.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/over-alto-rendimiento.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/over-alto-rendimiento@2x.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/over-seminario.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/over-seminario@2x.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/over-tesis-profesional.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/over-tesis-profesional@2x.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/seminario.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/seminario@2x.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/tesis-profesional.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/titulacion/tesis-profesional@2x.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/top-titulacion.png"
deleted:    "UNEVE/Graphic Assets/Titulacio\314\201n/top-titulacion@2x.png"
```

Untracked files:
  (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

```
UNEVE.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/
UNEVE.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/Thurman.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/
```

Comment: OK go to the folder within `Terminal.app` and type `git status` and post the results (in your question, not as a comment).

Comment: Done! I believe I could unstage those files? I'm kind of new to git.

Comment: That doesn't show the whole output.  Copy and paste it rather than using a screenshot.

Comment: There! The whole output is pasted. Doesn't look as bad as I thought it would, since it's a lot of text. 
What do you think the problem is?

Comment: Not really sure as the same files are both 'new' and 'deleted'

Answer (score 0):

Try to use UTF-8 compliant filenames and directories, probably the `Titulación/` directory is messing with your repository.

I had a similar problem, many suggest you implement the solution [featured here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581857/git-and-the-umlaut-problem-on-mac-os-x/15553796#15553796), yet it didn't work for me, you could try if that works for you.

Comment: I did try it, but it didn't work either for me. The project is almost done. I just have to uncheck those conflicting files every time I commit. It's kind of annoying but it has taught me a lesson. Thanks a lot! :)